# Filter Collections From A Property With Collections Linq

Tags: linq

I have an object Called MyConnection with a property of Sources which is of type List I am having trouble writing linq code to find all the MyConnections in a List where a connection has a Source of "".

I tried this but it doesnt seem to run..

```
MyConnection initialActivity = currentActivities.ToList().Where(x => x.Sources.Contains(String.Empty));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable<MyConnection>` not a single `MyConnection`. So you could enumerate all in a `foreach` or take one f.e. with `First`.

```
IEnumerable<MyConnection> allWithEmptySource = currentActivities
    .Where(con => con.Sources.Any(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
if(allWithEmptySource.Any())
{
    MyConnection first = allWithEmptySource.First();
}
```

Comment: `Any` isn't really the solution here, assuming the source really is `""` not `null`; `Contains` is better to use for an equality check as it can shortcut on an `ICollection`.

Comment: @Rawling: Why is `Any` not correct? He wants to "find all the `MyConnections` in a List where a connection has a Source of `String.Empty`." So there might be multiple sources in a connection. But if any of these is empty he wants that `MyConnection`.

Comment: So the problem _isn't_ that he's using `Contains` not `Any`, it's that he's trying to store the result in a single item rather than an `IEnumerable`. `Any` _works_ in this case, but it's not what is wrong with the original code and it's potentially a backwards step from `Contains`.

Comment: @Rawling: You're right. The core problem is that he cannot assign an `IEnumerable<MyConection>` to a single object. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`.Where()` returns a *sequence* of matching elements.

You can't assign that to a variable of type `MyConnection`.

Instead, you can call methods like `.Last()` to get a single element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to get *one* activity that has a Source of "", rather than *all* of them, use

```
MyConnection initialActivity = currentActivities.ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sources.Contains(String.Empty));
```

which will give you `null` if there are no such activities, andj ust the first if there are one or more.

Alternatively to [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx), use:

- [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) to give you the first but throw an exception if there are none
- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) to give you a single match and throw an exception of there are 0 or >1 matches
- [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) to give you a single match or no match, andthrow and exception if there are >1 matches.

If you want *all* of them, you return type will be an `IEnumerable<MyConnection>`, not a single one:

```
IEnumerable<MyConnection> initialActivities = = currentActivities.ToList()
    .Where(x => x.Sources.Contains(String.Empty));
```

You can then `foreach` over this, or call `ToList` or `ToArray` on it to get a list or an array.

N.B. You probably *don't* need to be calling `.ToList()` in the *middle* of your line here.